# What is this wide split in the Kmoch nimzo between stockfish's evaluation and master-level move choice?

Tags: engines, theory, evaluation, database, nimzo-indian

In the Kmoch Nimzo Indian (sometimes called the f3 nimzo)

```
[FEN ""]  
1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Bb4 4. f3 d5 5. a3 Bxc3 6. bxc3 c5 (6... dxc4!? 7. e4)
```

The move `6...c5` is the most popular continuation at master level according to Lichess's master database by far. However, stockfish "cloud" analysis lists `6...dxc4` as the top choice, which less than 1% of masters chose (and scored poorly). Since this is a cloud evaluation it is presumed to be deep analysis done beforehand, not a shallow depth search running in a browser.

At first glance, it looks like the cloud analysis is simply wrong. `dxc4` allows the immediate `e4`, which makes white's opening look like a strategic success! On the other hand, it seems unlikely to me that a high depth engine would make such a positional error.

Is it possible to say that `dxc4` is a valid continuation that hasn't been explored? Or is this simply a case where an engine misevaluates a position?

Comment: I guess sometimes masters aren't comfortable in certain positions that an engine is comfortable in. After 6...dxc4 7.e4 b5 8.a4 c6 9.Ba3 I'd rather be White.

Comment: Knowing what I know about engines, I would say it sees the opportunity to create an isolated a pawn weakness as a larger advantage than the central disadvantage. Also, having pushed f3, it might evaluate your long-term king safety as lower. I don't know of any engine v engine games in this position, but I don't think you can say the engine evaluation is wrong. The best you can say is it's not very human.